# How to make document.querySelector work in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I work on a website and I got a javascript function that doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6. 
I know

```
document.querySelector(selector)
```

only work [in Internet Explorer 8+](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

What could I do to make it work in IE6?

(I don't try to make it work for the fun of it ;) )

Comment: Why would you want to torture yourself like that?

Comment: please don't. Let it go down in the burning hell..where it shall meet its fate. I've heard Satan is waiting for IE6

Comment: Getting colours on a BW display...

Comment: You'd have to pollyfill it IF its required by a client (which I assume it is, you wouldn't do it for fun) maybe even use something like jquery if legacy support is required. (Or maybe just use sizzle if its only the selecting you want)

Comment: IF a client has a large share of users on ie6 (god forbid) then its more then acceptable that they should require ie6 compatability

Comment: That is exact, some clients still use IE6... (unfortunatly)

Comment: You could loop through document.all and filter by id and class
or
use document.getElementsByTagName or document.getElementsByClassName

make sure you feature test for querySelectorAll first
if(document.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 9):

I strongly encourage you not to try to support IE6 any longer.

---

But you can add `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` using [this very clever trick from an Ajaxian article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/creating-a-queryselector-for-ie-that-runs-at-native-speed). The article actually gets it a bit wrong, it adds something called `querySelector` that does `querySelectorAll` instead. I've fixed the name here:

```
/*@cc_on
if (!document.querySelectorAll)
    document.querySelectorAll = function(selector)
    {
        var head = document.documentElement.firstChild;
        var styleTag = document.createElement("STYLE");
        head.appendChild(styleTag);
        document.__qsResult = [];

        styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsResult.push(this))}";
        window.scrollBy(0, 0);
        head.removeChild(styleTag);

        var result = [];
        for (var i in document.__qsResult)
            result.push(document.__qsResult[i]);
        return result;
    }
@*/
```

Although I would **never** countenance using `for-in` like that; [details and alternatives in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

And by inference, `querySelector`:

```
/*@cc_on
if (!document.querySelector)
    document.querySelector = function(selector)
    {
        var head = document.documentElement.firstChild;
        var styleTag = document.createElement("STYLE");
        head.appendChild(styleTag);
        document.__qsResult = [];

        styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsResult.push(this))}";
        window.scrollBy(0, 0);
        head.removeChild(styleTag);

        // Return first result only               
        return document.__qsResult[0] || null;
    }
@*/
```

---

Note that neither of the above adds `Element#querySelector` or `Element#querySelectorAll` (the versions that look only within an element), just `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`. And you can't add the `Element` versions on IE6 without adding them to *each individual element*, since IE6 doesn't support element prototypes.

Comment: @AmitJoki: :-) Not *me*, I just remembered having read about a trick some years back, found it fairly quickly with a search.

Comment: Actually, it is good to still support IE 6 in certain areas of business such as computer maintenance companies so that people with IE6 can use the website to know who to pay to upgrade their browser (and probably their OS) because for some people, its just a miracle they're able to work the mouse.

Comment: HI T.J, I am trying to use your code above in my project. I am having some troubles though. Could you please have a look at my question and see what you think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539726/ie7-queryselector-not-finding-elements

Answer (score 4):

You could use a polyfill, like this [one](https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575), however still using IE6, is the IT analogue of necromancy.

The mentioned polyfill is based on *polyfill.js*, which can be found [here](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/polyfill.js#L655), this provides polyfills for a lot of ECMA 5 functions.

I will post the current state of the script, maybe it will useful in the future (though I really hope, it won't be :) ):

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
    document.querySelectorAll = function (selectors) {
        var style = document.createElement('style'), elements = [], element;
        document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(style);
        document._qsa = [];

        style.styleSheet.cssText = selectors +
                '{x-qsa:expression(document._qsa && document._qsa.push(this))}';
        window.scrollBy(0, 0);
        style.parentNode.removeChild(style);

        while (document._qsa.length) {
            element = document._qsa.shift();
            element.style.removeAttribute('x-qsa');
            elements.push(element);
        }
        document._qsa = null;
        return elements;
    };
}

if (!document.querySelector) {
    document.querySelector = function (selectors) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
        return (elements.length) ? elements[0] : null;
    };
}
```

Comment: The updated polyfill you mentioned now can be found [here](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/polyfill.js#L4599)