# Alternatives for querySelectorAll() for embedded browser

Tags: javascript, polyfills, selectors-api

I'm writing an application that will run on an embedded old browser (I mean really old browser. User agent: `ANTGalio/2.1.19.12.2.1.19.12.020.3.0.00; vxWorks-6.3`).

This browser don't support the function `querySelectorAll` or `querySelector`. I would like to know some alternative for those functions which will do the same job.

If there is no function which will do this, where can I get the code of the `querySelector` function, so I can try to write it by hand with JavaScript.

Comment: What *does* the browser support? Which browser are you asking about specifically?

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#dom--events. Alternatively, is jQuery an option?

Comment: [Here's the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28194786/1048572) about IE6

Comment: To be precise, this is the user agent from the browser: `ANTGalio/2.1.19.12.2.1.19.12.020.3.0.00; vxWorks-6.3`

Answer (score 0):

> If there is not function which do this.

There is … it's `querySelector`. That's why it was created. Before it existed we had to use other methods.

> Where can I get the code of the querySelector function?

There will be a custom implementation for each browser, usually written in C++, so probably not a whole lot of use to you.

[Sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/) provides a selector library that does a similar job. It is used by jQuery as a fallback for older browsers. It is 2277 lines lines long: Not something you want to try recreating from scratch.

You could also look at using features like `getElementById`, `getElementByClassName`, `parentNode` and so on instead of expressing things in terms of selectors.

Comment: I know about `querySelector` but I'm running in a browser which don't have those functions natively. That's why I'm asking for alternatives. And I tried Sizzle, it didn't work too.

Comment: @VitorVillar — My point was that querySelector was created to fulfil a need. If there was a drop in replacement that already existed in browsers it wouldn't have needed to be created in the first place.

Comment: @VitorVillar What did not work when you tried Sizzle?