# Change list item's margin using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, margin, listitem

I am trying to use JavaScript to dynamically change the right margin for a horizontal list. I have created a variable called "space" that equals the margin quantity that I want. Now I need to make the right margin for each list item equal to the "space" variable.

To be more specific, I'm having trouble with how to reference the list items within my JavaScript file. I can reference elements by class and id using `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementById`, respectively, but I really need to refer to an `<a>` link within a class. That is, in css I could manually modify the margin with:

```
.menu-item a {
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;   
}
```

**Notice I need the "a" in the css selector reference. How do I get this reference into Javascript?**

Here is some html:

```
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item" id="menuItem"><a href="item0.html">Item 0</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" id="menuItem"><a href="item1.html">Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" id="menuItem"><a href="item2.html">Item 2</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" id="menuItem"><a href="item3.html">Item 3</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" id="menuItem"><a href="item4.html">Item 4</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" id="menuItem"><a href="item5.html">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And here is some css:

```
.container{
  width:auto;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.menu-item a {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  float:left;    
}
```

And here is some javascript:

```
var space = (document.getElementById("container").offsetWidth - 450)/6;

var menuItem = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"); /*this line is the problem*/

spacer();
function spacer () {
  menuItem.style.margin = "0 " + space + "px 0 0"; /*and this line is potentially incorrect as well*/
}
```

As requested, I will take this opportunity to mention that I am after a solution that is compatible with all browsers. Thanks

Comment: Why are you assigning the same `ID` attribute to different tag elements? Each `ID` attribute should be unique to each individual tag element.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".menuItem a");`

Comment: is there a solution that's compatible with all browsers?

Comment: @Normajean Snel23 solution should be compatible with all modern browsers

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I noticed that when I copied it over. Is there anything wrong with doing so?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp I need something that is compatible with all browsers

Comment: @Normajean I might not understand which browser do you need to support, but `document.querySelector()` comptability is pretty good https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using it, as long as you use it correctly. It will only return the first result it finds, but if you want all of them use `document.querySelectorAll(".menuItem a")` which returns an array of all matches

Comment: I want something compatible with all browsers. Yes this includes IE 6 & 7.

Comment: Change your question to add this information, because otherwise people will not assume such requirements

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194786/how-to-make-document-queryselector-work-in-ie6) is a question about using `document.querySelector()` in IE 6. Note: the top answer suggests to no longer support IE6 any longer (it is extremely outdated.. the answer suggests to no longer support it and it was posted in 2015..) but does provide a workaround

Comment: @Snel23 I wouldn't suggest you to worry about compatibility for IE 6 - 8, imagine doing all the workarounds for every single function that you write

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I can't change my project scope.

Comment: @Normajean - how are you testing in IE6?

Comment: Are you guys saying there is no other way to refer to a link in a html file using javascript other than document.querySelector() ?

Comment: No, there is a workaround as provide it by @Snel23 but we wouldn't suggest you to support these older browsers, but if you actually have to do this for whatever reason, use his link as a pointer, good luck!

Comment: @Normajean - most of what you wish to be done can probably be done in IE6-- however, it may be difficult and involve a lot of troubleshooting-- IE6 is a very old browser.  Honestly, while I am hesitant to recommend jQuery, the easiest thing for you may be to leverage jQuery 1.12 if you _really_ need to support IE6.  That said, I am going to take a crack and see if I can find something that will probably work in IE6-- although I don't currently have a great way to test for IE6.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I *believe* that this will work for you.  I do not have a great way to test in IE6 right now, but the code being used *should* be compatible with IE6.

In the demo below, I create a function called `updateAnchorMarginsTo` that accepts a number and sets the left margin of all the anchors to the number passed.  For the demo I then have it toggle every second between setting the left margin to `0` and to `20`.

(I also removed all the duplicate `id` values, as that is invalid HTML and is sure to generate problems).

First, we check to see if [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is defined-- if not, we might be in an older browser.  We polyfill it with [this helpful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i#6584684).

Inside `updateAnchorMarginsTo` we can then use `getElementsByClassName` to get all the `li` elements with the `menu-item` `class`.  We use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to iterate over each of those `li` elements and leverage [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) (supported in IE6) to fetch all `a` elements that `li` might contain, and grab the first one (we know there will only be one).  Finally, we update the [`style` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) of each of those `anchors`, which [is supported in older IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119300/setattribute-is-not-working-for-style-attribute-on-ie).

```js
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
  // if we are below IE9 we have to polyfill getElementsByClassName...
  // This solution courtesy of:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i
  document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) {
    var retnode = [];
    var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      if((' ' + elem[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cl + ' ') > -1) retnode.push(elem[i]);
    }
    return retnode;
  }; 
}

function updateAnchorMarginsTo(numPixels) {
  var menuListItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
  var currentMenuAnchor, currentMenuListItem;

  for (var i = 0; i < menuListItems.length; i++) {
      currentMenuListItem = menuListItems[i];
      currentMenuAnchor = currentMenuListItem.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      currentMenuAnchor.style.marginLeft = numPixels.toString() + 'px';
  }
}

var margins = 0;

setInterval(function () {
  margins = margins === 0 ? 20 : 0;
  updateAnchorMarginsTo(margins);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="item0.html">Item 0</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="item1.html">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="item2.html">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="item3.html">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="item4.html">Item 4</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="item5.html">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Give it a try-- like I said, I don't have IE6 testing infrastructure setup, so I am interested to see if this works.

IE6 is, at this point, an ancient browser.  If you *must* support it, it will take some effort.  If possible, it may be wise to lean on an older jQuery version to assist you.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much. I really appreciate it. I'll give it a go. Thanks again

Comment: Great, please report back-- if it works, don't forget to vote up and accept as the correct answer.